# Compute Cech cohomology of a subscheme defined by a homogeneous equations in $P^2_k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

I am trying to compute the cohomology in Hartshorens's exercise 4.7 in chapter3. Given a subscheme $Y$ in $X=P^2_k$ defined by a homogeneous equations $f(x_0,x_1,x_2)$ of degree $d$, and point (1,0,0) is not contained in $Y$. I want to compute its Cech cohomology. And the following is what I attempt so far.

First, according to the hint, we can cover $Y$ with two affine subset $U=X \cap ${$x_1 \neq0$} and $V=X \cap${$x_2\neq0$}. Then, we give the sheaf of regular functions $\mathcal{O}_Y$ on $Y$. On $U$($V$, resp.), that is $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_U)=k[\frac{x_0}{x_1},\frac{x_2}{x_1}]/(f)$ (and $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{O}_V)=k[\frac{x_0}{x_2},\frac{x_1}{x_2}]/(f)$, resp.).

And we define $d$: $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_U)\oplus\Gamma(V,\mathcal{O}_V)\to \Gamma(U\cap V, \mathcal{O}_{U\cap V})$ simply by addition. That is

$<g[\frac{x_0}{x_1},\frac{x_2}{x_1}]/(f), h[\frac{x_0}{x_2},\frac{x_1}{x_2}]/(f)>\to (g+h)/(f)$ in $<k[\frac{x_0}{x_1},\frac{x_2}{x_1},\frac{x_0}{x_2},\frac{x_1}{x_2}]/(f)>$

Now, $H^0=ker$ $d$, and this can be done only when $g,h\in (f)$, so $dimH^0=1$;
to compute $H^1$,  we notice that the cokernel is of the form {$\frac{x_0^i}{x_1^j x_2^k}:j+k=i$}. But I got stuck in this step, and I don't know how to use the condition of $f$ to determine the expilict form of $H^1(Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$.

Am I right so far? Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: I just want to point out a couple of things in your calculation. 1) f is of degree d > 0, so, in each affine piece, you need to change $f$ accordingly. 2) your target space can be identified as $k[x_0/x_1,(x_1/x_2),(x_1/x_2)^{-1}]$. Under this identification, the first component in $d$ is the identity, but the second component, you need to identify $x_0/x_2$ as $x_0/x_2 x_2/x_1$. The advantage of this identification is that now you may view the target space as the right half on an $x_0/x_1,x_1/x_2$-plane (modulo the image of $f$).

Comment: @Youngsu -Well, thank you for your simplification. And, can you tell me how to get through the final step?